# Right alignment of description items (similar to default enumerate)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

Let us consider the following example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]  {geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
Under 'enumerate' environment :
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\end{enumerate}


Under 'description' environment :
\begin{description}
\item[(i)] Text
\item[(ii)] Text
\item[(iii)] Text
\item[(iv)] Text
\item[(v)] Text
\item[(vi)] Text
\item[(vii)] Text
\item[(viii)] Text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

**Output** :

[image]

I want to get the second list environment using  `\begin{enumerate}`  and
`\end{enumerate}`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) instead, since it gives you control over both list environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
Under \verb|enumerate| environment:
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\roman*)}]%[(i)]
  \item Text
  \item Text
  \item Text
  \item Text
  \item Text
  \item Text
  \item Text
  \item Text
\end{enumerate}

Under \verb|description| environment:
\begin{description}[itemindent=0pt,align=right]
  \item[(i)] Text
  \item[(ii)] Text
  \item[(iii)] Text
  \item[(iv)] Text
  \item[(v)] Text
  \item[(vi)] Text
  \item[(vii)] Text
  \item[(viii)] Text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Alignment is selected using the `align=<style>` option.